# Passing data from Activity to IntentService (Android SDK)

Tags: android, android-intent

I create a service that is running in the background for the entire duration of application.
I chose an **IntentService** for this.
For me **intent.putExtra(....)** work only on start the service.
My problem is that sometimes I want to passing data from **Activity** to **IntentService** not only at start.
Thank You

Comment: `IntentService` is designed for transactional bits of work, not to be "running in the background for the entire duration of application".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just transfer data to `IntentService` by start, because the `IntentService` will always has the only one instance in the whole application life cycle.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [bind](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Basics) interface to interact with service public methods.

From documentation:

```
public class LocalService extends Service {
    // Binder given to clients
    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    // Random number generator
    private final Random mGenerator = new Random();

    /**
     * Class used for the client Binder.  Because we know this service always
     * runs in the same process as its clients, we don't need to deal with IPC.
     */
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        LocalService getService() {
            // Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call public methods
            return LocalService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    /** method for clients */
    public int getRandomNumber() {
      return mGenerator.nextInt(100);
    }
}
```